# Is there a delay in doing svn checkout after svn copy

Tags: svn

Is there any delay between when the svn copy finishes and when you can do an svn checkout of that new branch ? We are dealing with such an issue. It seems that when we run a script to create a new branch and check it out immediately after the svn copy finishes, the checkout is not pulling all of the files, which leads me to believe that the svn repository is not fully updated until some time after the svn copy command is completed.

does anyone know anything about this ?

Comment: as bahrep points out the SVN architecture is carefully planned around transaction integrity. This means you should see the whole dir-tree after a commited copy operation. I think the checkout runs into technically difficulties. 
Is there an output ending with "At revision xyz."?

Answer (score 0):

[`svn copy URL URL`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.copy.html) is an *instant* operation. Read the documentation.